# ffmpeg select subclips from large video bash and create outputfile names

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I am using bash command on a Mac Terminal. For each of the 250 .mp4 files in a directory I need to create a new outputfile which extracts 4 subclips from each inputfile: 1st subclip (from second 10 to 20), 2nd subclip (10 seconds at a 33% stage of the inputfile), 3rd subclip (10 seconds at a 66% of the inputfile), and a 4th subclip (10 seconds starting 30seconds before the end of the inputfile). Each inputfile has a different length of about 10-15minutes.

I tried with one inputfile and the following bash script works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select='between(t, 10, 20) + between(t, 197, 207) + between(t, 393, 403) + between(t, 570,580)',
setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -qscale 0 -af "aselect='between(t, 10, 20) + 
between(t, 197, 207) + between(t, 393, 403) + between(t, 570, 580)', 
asetpts=N/SR/TB" outputfile.mp4; done
```

However, I don't know how to loop it over the 250 mp4 files. Specifically, I have 2 issues:

1. The above code shows specific seconds I manually checked from the inputfile I used to test the code.  I need to automatize the code according to the timings above.
2. Name the outputfile the same as the inputfile but adding "_1" suffix

In sum, I have a directory with inputfiles between 10-15minutes long:

```
inputfile1.mp4
inputfile2.mp4
inputfile3.mp4
.......
inputfile250.mp4
```

And I want the same directory with inputfiles and outputfiles together:

```
inputfile1.mp4
inputfile1_1.mp4 #this is 40 seconds long
inputfile2.mp4
inputfile2_1.mp4 #this is 40 seconds long
inputfile3.mp4
inputfile3_1.mp4 #this is 40 seconds long
.......
inputfile250.mp4
inputfile250_1.mp4 #this is 40 seconds long
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: *"I don't know how to loop it over the 250 mp4 files"* . What do you think the `for file *.mp4` is doing? Maybe you need to `cd /path/to/mp4Files/` at the top of that script? *"I want the same directory with inputfiles and outputfiles together"*. Save your new files to a work directory ,then move them after the for loop is done, back into you main dir. BTW, very nice use of `ffmpeg` options. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Making is a one-liner does not improve readability.

So, what you are doing is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" \
        -vf "select='between(t, 10, 20) \
        + between(t, 197, 207) + between(t, 393, 403) \
        + between(t, 570,580)', \
        setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
        -qscale 0 \ 
        -af "aselect='between(t, 10, 20) \
        + between(t, 197, 207) \
        + between(t, 393, 403) \
        + between(t, 570, 580)', \
        asetpts=N/SR/TB" \
        outputfile.mp4
done
```

To go into detail:

```
for file in *.mp4; do
```

This means, that you will do the `ffmpeg` for every file in the directory. This is, as Shelter pointed out, effectively looping over all the different files. But, since you are writing to a fixed filename (`outputfile.mp4`), only a single outputfile remains: the shortened version of the last mp4 in your loop.

So if you write the output to different files, you will see that, in fact, the `ffmpeg` is executed for all input-files.

If you are uncertain about you looping, try inserting `echo`s  to tell you what is going on.

As for the variable for the output-file: `${file%.mp4}_1.mp4` will probably do.

So, that means:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do
    outputfile=${file%.mp4}_1.mp4
    echo "Doing $file -> $outputfile"
    # the ffmpeg command
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Ljm! Yes, I know what the loop does. My issues were two: the seconds issue, which is still unresolved, and the output file name, which you solved! Thanks again. Let's see if some other user can give me some hints on programming the seconds issue